# Assume value exists if another value exists in Flow type checking

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible with flow.

I have a function that returns an object like this

```
{
  isChannel: boolean,
  channelName?: string,
  streamName?: string,
}
```

if `isChannel === true`, I know `channelName` will exist.

In many places in our codebase we have something like this

```
const { channelName, streamName, isChannel } = parseUri(uri);
const name = isChannel ? channelName.slice(1) : streamName;
```

The `slice(1)` is because the `channelName` includes a leading `@`. I know there are ways around this, but since this is all existing code, I'd rather not have to change it all.

Is there anyway to say this with flow types? If `isChannel` is true, `channelName` will exist, if `isChannel` is `false`, then it *might* exist.

```
if isChannel === true
then channelName: string
else channelName?: string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [union type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) where one type has `isChannel: true` and the other has `isChannel: false`:

```
type Channel = 
  | {| isChannel: false, channelName?: string, streamName?: string |}
  | {| isChannel: true, channelName: string, streamName?: string |};
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHZIgGygXigKClAHygG8iBLAZ3mVTQC4oAzBNCiAGigGNEV0A5BAFsIAfgYVgAJzJIA5p0lSIwwSPFQlsuYQC+eQiXJVetBtICuHbqYHCIE6dsXSVQtWMcz5egNxA)

Then you can refine the type by checking `isChannel` without having to check `channelName`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!